# Yank paste not working after trying to map clipboard to register

Tags: cut-copy-paste, paste

I tried making  clipboard work with yank paste. And now for some reason normal V+y and p doesn't work as intended anymore.
for example:

```
{
    pb.push(to_string(pb.top()).size());
    pb.pop();
}
```

normal yanking pasting not working here on the pop line. Here's the vimrc:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
set nocompatible
filetype on
syntax on
set smarttab
set autoindent
set smartindent
set cindent shiftwidth=4
set exrc
set mouse=a
set tabstop=4
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set clipboard=unnamedplus
set hls
set number relativenumber
set numberwidth=2
set cpoptions+=n
"vnoremap<C-c> "+y
"nmap<C-p> "+p
```

I've commented out the mapping thinking that would work. It didn't. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe should tell us exactly what  are the mode you are in, the keys you hit  and the result you expect.

Comment: I already said it. V+y and then p, or a normal copy paste. It releases other random registers out instead of pasting the last yank

Comment: Note that you have `clipboard=unnamedplus` (`:help 'clipboard'`).  Cf. [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)